# Mypy list shadowing

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I had a DRF (django-rest-framework) ViewSet class with some methods, and one of them is

```
def foobar(foo: list[str], bar: list[int]) -> bool:
    return ...
```

Today, when I implemented the `def list` method of the common [ViewSet class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), mypy started considering this new function instead the builtin list for the `list[str]` giving me some errors:

```
error: Function "path.to.the.class.list" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
note: Perhaps you need "Callable[...]" or a callback protocol?
error: "list?[builtins.str]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)  [attr-defined]
```

The problem is clear, the new function does shadowing.
The question is how do you usually avoid this problem?
In my personal case find a solution is quiet easy, I can just move my function to another class / file / outside this class and everything will work as expected.

I would like to collect other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is a built-in in Python, and it's good practice not to override it, for this very reason. Your new `list` function overrides the existing one, and you won't be able to access the original function in the same file.

I would usually recommend you renaming your function to something else. However, this doesn't seem possible in your case.

Another option you can consider is importing the `List` type

```py
from typing import List


def foobar(foo: List[str], bar: List[int]) -> bool:
    ...
```

A bit inconvenient, but it gets around your specific problem + it works the same way.

Edit: If you can't import List, you can make a type alias

```py
listAlias = list


class MyClass:
    def list(self):
        ...

    def foobar(self, foo: listAlias[str], bar: listAlias[int]) -> bool:
        ...
```

Or you can import the builtins module like in [Joel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105927/12370337)

Comment: You're right... but the DRF guys decided to call the method `list` :( If type with `List` instead of `list`, pyupgrade will roll it back https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade#pep-585-typing-rewrites

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll edit my answer quickly with another workaround.

Comment: In some sense, `list` is only *temporarily* shadowed, as it's only (re)defined for the execution of the `class` statement. Once the class is created, it's a class attribute, not a variable in any other scope. For *most* classes, it's only type hints that will see this as a problem. As such, you can move the `listAlias` definition into the `class` statement as well; it won't be needed outside the definition. (You might want to pair it with a `del listAlias` at the end of the statement to avoid an unnecessary class attribute.)

Comment: @chepner makes sense, thanks for the insight. This problem seemed quite strange to me.

Comment: @joel sorry about that. Your original answer didn't work cause you didn't import builtins. I'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

First choice is don't use builtin names for custom objects. If that's not possible, disambiguate with

```
import builtins

builtins.list[str]
```

or `ClassName.list` as appropriate

Comment: `__builtins__` is an implementation detail of CPython. Use `builtins` (which you need to import) instead.

Comment: @chepner thanks. I thought it was `builtins`, but it errored in the REPL. Wasn't aware it needed an import

Comment: If `builtins` itself were in the builtin namespace, it could get overriden. As the `import` is a kind of assignment, this ensures that the name can always be available to provide access to the builtin scope.